# Subclass declares "no appropriate default constructor available"

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, subclass, default-constructor

I made a class with a default constructor and a subclass. When I try to create an instance of the subclass using a default constructor, I get the errors
C2512 (no appropriate default constructor available) and
E0289 (no instance of constructor "Faculty::Faculty" matches the argument list).

```
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

class Person {
protected:
    string name;
public:
    Person() {
        setName("Belethor");
    }

    Person(const string& pName) {
        setName(pName);
    }

    void setName(const string& pName) {
        name = pName;
    }
};

class Faculty : public Person {
private:
    string department;
public:
    Faculty(const string& fname, const string& d) : Person(fname) {
        department = d;
    }
};
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "college.h" 
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Faculty> prof = make_shared<Faculty>();
    return 0;
}
```

Does class `Faculty` not inherit the default constructor defined in class `People`?

Comment: For other visitors:  Here is a [long list of errors](https://godbolt.org/z/GK4Ka66f3) produced by this code.  I suspect that this isn't the real code that OP is compiling.

Comment: You provide user defined constructor for `Faculty`, disabling the default auto generated default constructor.

Comment: *Does class Faculty not inherit the default constructor defined in class People?* -- No.  You wrote the `Faculty` class so that it can only be constructed with two arguments.

Comment: I tried only including the relevant code by retyping it into the question for clarity, but that created some issues. I'm replacing it with all of the code.

Comment: A [mre] would be more appropriate than "all of the code".

Comment: Constructors are not inherited. Each class has to define its own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in comments, no, you have explicitly stated that `Faculty` has only one constructor and it takes two arguments. Now, you *could* provide default values for those arguments, though I'm not sure what values would make sense as defaults in a case like this.

Your classes also need to be followed by a semicolon, and you can initialize `department` in your member initialization list.

```
        Faculty(const string& fname, Discipline d) 
        : Person(fname), department(d) 
        { }
```